# GDBM in Standard Lib missing or is it just me?

Tags: ruby

[GDBM](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/gdbm/rdoc/index.html) looks interesting, a kind of persistent Hash or a key-value store. However the example code does not run:

```
require 'gdbm'
```

results in this error:

> cannot load such file -- gdbm (LoadError)

I'm using Ruby 1.9.3 on Ubuntu. Is the documentation wrong or is something wrong with my Ruby install?

Comment: Typing `require GDBM` would result in an entirely different error than you're getting. What did you type *exactly*?

Comment: @Andrew Marshall just copy-pasted the code from the docs, but i must have messed up somewhere. Thanks and edited.

Comment: This works fine for me. How did you install Ruby?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GDBM is a library that provides an API to the GNU Database Library, which you might not have installed.  Ruby Standard Library documentation advises it's available **only if** the underlying library is available on your system.  (No point offering a library that doesn't connect to anything!)  Install libgdbm3 with apt-get, confirm you have your library ('locate libgdbm' e.g.), and reinstall/update your ruby 1.9 to incorporate the library into your ruby.

Comment: I find it strange that it is not mentioned in [ruby-doc.org](http://ruby-doc.org//stdlib-2.1.5/libdoc/gdbm/rdoc/GDBM.html)

Comment: Linux is mentioned below by Fernando Almeida on OS X Yosemite with Homebrew  i had to `brew unlink gdbm && brew link gdbm` because libgdbm was already installed but not correctly linked. You can also install it via `brew install gdbm`. Then you can `gem install gdbm`. If the **libgdbm** library is not available on your system you may incur in this error: `Could not open library 'libgdbm.dylib'`

Answer (score 3):

With ruby 2.1.2 and Rbenv I solved this with:

```
$ apt-get install libgdbm3
$ ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdbm.so.3 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdbm.so
$ gem install gdbm
```

now it works

```
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'gdbm'
=> true
```

Answer (score 0):

Compiling on Linux with gcc. First make sure it's there at all.

```
$ find /usr/include -name *dbm*
```

If you can't find it then you need to install it.

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install libgdbm-dev
```

That done I could #include <gdbm-ndbm.h> and compile with this.

$ gcc -o holidays -I/usr/include/gdbm holidays.c -lgdbm_compat -lgdbm